# PHP redirect behaving weird in Chrome only

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Using PHP, I have multiple software pages where the download link to the respective software is a PHP redirect. Basically, I have a "Download" button, that has a URL like https://www.example.com/software/ which redirects to the external URL that hosts the setup file.

The redirect script is pretty simple:

```
  <?php
  if($download_url)
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: '.$download_url);
  exit;
  ?>
```

The php redirect works fine on all browsers, but Google Chrome referred by my site. Anywhere I place this link on my site, I click on the link, nothing happens, it behaves as it should redirect and download something but stops. If I copy-paste the redirect link in a new tab in Chrome, the redirect works perfectly. In Firefox, IE, Opera, the link works perfectly when you click on it.

I tried many things, redirecting using JS, changing the redirect url structure, testing the redirect link on other domains (it worked). I simply don't understand why Chrome doesn't like this redirect clicked from my domain but otherwise works perfectly.

I'm desperate :)

Comment: May not be the cause of your error, but you have a logic error in the code snippet you posted... the first `header()` statement is only called when `$download_url` evaluates to _true_, however, the `Location` header is set unconditionally, regardless of `$download_url`.

Comment: That's correct, I forgot the brackets for the if, but as you stated, it doesn't solve my problem. The redirect itself works when launched from a standalone Chrome tab or any other browser.

Comment: What are the headers returned to the browser? Have you checked the dev tools and confirmed you are not seeing a cached response? (There should be no difference between browsers, unless the HTTP response headers are "mangled" or you are seeing a cached response.)

Comment: Returned by the redirected link or? Not sure I understand the question. I've checked the headers of the redirected links, they are fine. Again, the redirected links don't work only when clicked from the site. If I copy paste them in another tab, they work with no issue. Also, all browsers work with them no matter what, even when on my site. I've cleared Chrome's cache, cookies and sessions, ran in incognito mode etc. No luck.

Comment: "don't work only when clicked from the site" - are you doing anything with the HTTP `Referer` header? That's potentially the only difference between following a link and a direct request (as well as the cache - but that would seem to be discounted).

Comment: I've noticed that Chrome gives me the following error:  Mixed Content: The site at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://cdn.example.com/bootcamp/file.exe' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked." Both resources are on https, how's this mixed? Edit: both links have https

Comment: Ah, if there are "mixed content" warnings then that could break the redirect. Note that it states "redirected _through_" - maybe there is an intermediary redirect via HTTP? The "network traffic" in the browser dev tools should alert you to any redirect chain. (?)